# Does a shader material keep being rendered in Three.js, when no input value changed?

Tags: three.js

I'm programming shader materials on a smarthone with Three.js, so saving GPU performance is critical to me.

### Situations:

Lots of planes are designed as UI interfaces in my application, and will play animations(shader animation) in the beginning, or in many user-interaction activities. After animation, those UIes are in a "static" status(a "static" image combined by shader), no need to do combination in shader again and again(yes, it renders, the "render" here means "shader multitexture, or program combination" ). If can't stop those meanless rendering, it'll consume a big percentage of GPU performence.

### Questions:

As we knows, when any input values of the shader material are changed, whether "needupdate" is "false" or not, webGLRender will update the output material.

But, if no input value of the Uniforms is changed, will the webGLRender render it again, or just abandon the rendering? This is Question 1.

I've read the "webGLRender.js" code, with a bad understanding, still not very sure about how shader materials are rendered.(from code, i believe it keeps on rendering, while not very sure.)

The Question 2:
If webGLRender keeps rendering the shader material, even no input value is changed, is there a way to stop webGLRender from rendering the "unchanged" shader material, to save GPU performance?

Here's my simple test:

fragmentShader:

```
uniform float col; 
void main() {
   gl_FragColor = vec4(col, 0.58, 0.06, 1.0);
}
```

vertexShader:

```
void main() {
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position.x+5.0, position.y, position.z+25.0, 1.0); 
}
```

Javascript code:

```
var cube1, geo1, mat1;

function newbox2(){
    geo1 = new THREE.BoxGeometry(12, 4, 2);

    mat1 = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {
        uniforms: {
            col: { type: 'f', value: 1.0 },
        },
        vertexShader: "void main() {gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position.x+5.0, position.y, position.z+25.0, 1.0); }",
        fragmentShader: "uniform float col; void main() {gl_FragColor = vec4(col, 0.58, 0.06, 1.0);}"
    });

    cube1 = new THREE.Mesh(geo1, mat1);
    scene.add(cube1);   

    cube1.position.set(5, 5, 10);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: A shader is not "rendered"...  a shader is used to render something. In your case, it is used to render the mesh you created. I don't known Three.js well, but I guess "webGLRender" renders the frame each loop whatever you do with your uniforms, because this is how WebGL is intented to work.

Comment: Yes, it is. Shader material is used for mesh(a plane).  The mesh(plane) is designed as a UI interface in 3D space, and will play an animation in the beginning. After animation, this UI is in a "static" status(a "static" image combined by shader), no need to render it again and again. This 3D application has lots of such kind of UI, consumes a big percent of GPU performence.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you have any kind of motion, animation, orbit controls and such, and a loop, the renderer will render everything every frame. Even your camera changing position is considered a change in the shader "input values" (uniforms).
2. the only way to achieve something like this is to not render again.

Comment: Lots of planes are designed as UI interfaces in my application, and will play animations(shader animation) in the beginning. After animation, those UIes are in a "static" status(a "static" image combined by shader), no need to do combination in shader again and again(yes,it renders, but "my render" means "shader multitexture, or program combination" ). If can't stop those meanless rendering, it'll consume a big percent of GPU performence. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post some screenshots? If you don't clear an area of your buffer and you draw something again, you will draw things on top of it.  This is a very very broad question.

Comment: One idea may be to use the stencil buffer, write a mask for all your ui elements, then at one point just render the stuff around it...

Comment: Thank for your help.